# EJS: How can I recognize empty string and null string?

Tags: javascript, ejs

Suppose I that variable message is a String that can be null, empty, or any string. I want to do something only if message is not null. How can I do this?

```
<% if typeof message != 'undefined' %>

or 

<% if message %>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but why the [tag:java] tag? How is this question related to Java programming? Do you mean Javascript by chance?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels you are right. I deleted java. tnx

Answer (score 0):

```
if message != null
```

should do the trick and handle the exception for you.